# How to set the column width to be the whole QTableWidget width?

Tags: python, pyqt, width, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have an object of type QTableWidget. It contains only one column.
How do I set the column width to be the whole QTableWidget width?

[image: Graphical representation]

Also: is there a way to delete the header of the column?

Comment: `tableWidget.horizontalHeader().hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following (assuming your table widget is called `tableWidget`)...

```
tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

Comment: I finded  
**self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0,QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) ** but your method is easier to read ;)
thx :)